# Как можно сохранить картинку? Python

Tags: python, png, qrcode

Решил ради интереса написать простенький генератор QR кодов, и тут возникает вопрос, при запуске кода, картинка сохраняется в той папке, из которой произведён запуск, а как я могу сделать так, что бы она сохранялась в нужную мне папку?

```
import pyqrcode
import time


save = 0
QRString = input('Введите значения QR: ')
save = input('Введите название файла: ')
url = pyqrcode.create(QRString)
    
url.png( save+".PNG", scale = 8)
time.sleep(2)
```

Попробовал поискать в интернете, но ничего толком то и не понял. Может кто поможет?

Comment: Написано что первый аргумент метода `png` принимает путь к файлу либо поток. В вашем случае указывается только название файла и соответственно программа сохраняет его в текущую директорию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто перед названием файла введи путь

```
url.png(r'D:\example\1' + save + ".png", scale=8)
```

Comment: Использовать хардкод с конкатенацией для генерации пути сохранения файла - очень плохое решение! Следует использовать `pathlib.Path` или `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

Перед названием стоит написать место хранения фотки(если папки нет, то она сама будет создана)

```
save = input('папка/название файла')
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).